# Could not load type MvcApplication and 'mscorlib' must be referenced

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015, global-asax

I have been developing an MVC 5 web application in Visual Studio 2013 for some time now. Recently I started getting the following error whenever I try to run the project (debug locally):

`Could not load type 'MyWebsiteProject.MvcApplication'.`

The source error is in the Global.asax page according to the error page, but I am confident that is NOT the problem. I have searched for this error and there are a number of things that were mentioned to fix this, but none of them helped.

**Possible solutions that did not work:**

(1) Ensure the 'Inherits' tag in the Global.asax file points to the right namespace / class name. It does. The Global.asax file has:
`<%@ Application Codebehind="Global.asax.cs" Inherits="MyWebsiteProject.MvcApplication" Language="C#" %>`. The codebehind has:

```
namespace MyWebsiteProject
{
    public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        }
    }
}
```

Looks right to me.

(2) Clean / Rebuild / delete bin folder / restart Visual Studio. Tried numerous times, did not help.

(3) Make sure the output path is '\bin' and not something else. It is.

(4) Stop / restart IIS. Done, did not help. Restarted PC and everything numerous times, still did not help.

**Possibly related problems**
Whenever I go to edit a razor view page I am getting some strange problems. For one, my model class is being recognized but it is complaining that there is an ambiguous reference between two identical names. It literally lists `DatabaseLibrary.Setup` and `DatabaseLibrary.Setup` as the two ambiguous references even though the model is already completely spelled out: `@model IEnumerable<DatabaseLibrary.Setup>`. There is only one reference to `DatabaseLibrary` dll.

Furthermore, many classes like `IEnumerable` and `Html` and `ViewBag` are not recognized and it is telling me I should reference 'mscorlib', which I can't because it is already referenced by the build system.

**Possible cause(s)**
I am not entirely sure but I think this started happening after I have opened my project in Visual Studio 2015. The project files are all shared on Dropbox and I have worked on the project shortly on my secondary PC which only has VS2015, while my main PC has 2013. I did not upgrade the project or anything like that (did not need to) and it is loading just fine in 2013 as well, but I think that is when the problem started to appear.

Does anyone have any clue to what I can do to fix it?

Comment: I am getting desperate, I uninstalled VS2013 and installed VS2015 and it is still giving me the same problems. Meanwhile, it still works completely fine on my secondary PC, but not on my main PC. There must be something wrong with this PC but I can't figure it out......

Comment: It even happens on a brand new project with no changes. I might as well reinstall Windows at this rate cause I'm not going to solve this one...